# Create datasets based on a condition for each column in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, dataset

I have a table with hundreds of columns. I would like to create one dataset for each column with the observations that match a simple condition.

For examble here is my table (I take just 3 variables for the example but I have hundreds)

col  coll  colll

1     3    5

2     5    2

10   3    1

8     0    -10

my condition : >=5

I want in return three datasets dcol dcoll and dcolll with :

dcol :

col coll colll

10  3   1

8   0  -10

dcoll:

col coll colll

2     5    2

and dcolll

col coll colll

1    3     5

I thought about try to create an array with the name of my variables and then doing a loop with a datastep inside but I don't know how to do this and if it's what to do.

Thanks for your help!

Céline

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough.  First let's convert the print-out you shared into an actual dataset.

```
data have;
  input col coll colll ;
cards;
1 3 5
2 5 2
10 3 1
8 0 -10
;
```

Now just run a data step that generates multiple datasets.

```
data col coll colll;
  set have;
  if col>=5 then output col;
  if coll>=5 then output coll;
  if colll>=5 then output colll;
run;
```

If you would like a way to generate such code for whatever variables exist in the data you could get a list of the variable names and use that to generate the code.

```
proc transpose data=have(obs=0) out=names;
run;
filename code temp;
data _null_;
   file code ;
   put 'data ' @;
   do p=1 to nobs;
     set names point=p;
     put _name_ @;
   end;
   put ';' / '  set have;' ;
   do p=1 to nobs;
     set names point=p;
     put '  if ' _name_ '>=5 then output ' _name_ ';' ;
   end;
   put 'run;'
   stop;
 run;
 %include code / source2;
```